# Ping packet lost

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, connection

I am new at Ubuntu.internet drops randomly and after few min start then drop. So, when i ping to my default gateway 80%packet got lost. And internet is running well on windows10(Dual boot).kindly help as soon as possible.

Comment: Try pinging your own interface IP and see if any packets are dropped? If not then most likely hardware check cable or try to ping something else on LAN?

Answer (score 0):

The default gateway is just the IP used to connect to your router. Eg. My gateway is 10.0.0.2 and if I put that in my browser it connects to my router. Your default gateway is just sort of a link to your router, well it is.

If you have packetloss on it then it should be your cable, hardware or the modem/router itself.

What you can do to check your network is to ping google.com or their DNS 8.8.8.8

If you have a newly installed ubuntu then try to update it with `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` then if you want to upgrade to the latest version of ubuntu use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If this didnt resolve anything then check if it is running a DHCP server. It may be trying to act as a router.

Use this `sudo ps -ef | grep dhcp`

If it returns with anything try to kill the processes.

Comment: this is my ping details PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=31 ttl=56 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=32 ttl=56 time=48.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=56 time=48.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=68 ttl=56 time=50.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=69 ttl=56 time=49.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=104 ttl=56 time=53.6 ms                               --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
114 packets transmitted, 15 received, 86% packet loss, time 113813ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.847/49.765/56.100/2.341 ms

Comment: No hardware problem. Ethernet working well in windows (dual boot)